# Better way to handle nested subscription

Tags: angular, subscription

I have below code

```
this.subscriptions.push(this.loginservice.userdetails$.valueChanges().subscribe(data => {  // subscribing for user data... if any of the logged in user details changed
  this.lgUser = data;
  this.toFilter.subscribe(filter => {   // subject filter value of a dropdown
    this.subscriptions.push(this.service.getlist(this.lgUser.oid, filter).subscribe(res => { // subscribing to get list data
     // do some operation on res
    }));
    this.subscriptions.push(this.service.countValue(this.lgUser.oid, filter).subscribe(res => { // subscribing to get count value
      this.lCount = res.length;
    }));

  })
}));
```

How can make it more prominent way

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I think this is clean :

```js
this.loginservice.userdetails$
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(
    tap(data => this.lgUser = data),
    switchMap(data => this.toFilter.pipe(
      tap(filter => this.service.countValue(this.lgUser.oid, filter)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(res => this.lCount = res.length)
    )),
    switchMap(filter => this.service.getlist(this.lgUser.oid, filter))
  ).subscribe(res => {
    // Do something on res
  });
```

- You start by listening on changes on your input.
- At every change, you update `this.lgUser` with the content of the input.
- You then switch to `toFilter` and cancel the previous pending requests with `switchMap`
- You call `countValue` once to get the data and store it in `lCount`
- Then you switch to `service.getList` and cancel previous pending requests
- you are left with a single sbuscription, where you can what you want.

Comment: But it will execute if there is any change in filter or in data other than userdetails

Comment: Well, except the readability, I don't think so ... I would need to see it in action to be sure

Comment: I have just started learning angular. so in terms of readability my code looks more readable to me :)